# как увеличить array с помощью ref чтобы не потерять данные?

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] names = new string[5] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

        string[] copynames = names;
        for (int i = 0; i < copynames.Length; i++) {

            copynames[i] = names[i];
            Console.WriteLine(copynames[i]);
        }


        ResizeArray(ref names, names.Length + 1);

        names[5] = "F";


        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(names[i]);

        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static void ResizeArray(ref string[] array, int newSize)
    {

         if (array.Length == newSize)
         {

             return;

         }

       array = new string[newSize];

    }
```

//надо  увеличить первый массив и добавить 1 элемент, так чтобы не потерять данные. Подскажите как написать увеличение массива в ResizeArray функции.

Comment: [Array.Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.resize) есть для таких целей.

Comment: Нужно именно массив изменять?Можно списки использовать.Насколько помню размер массива изменить нельзя,вместо этого создается новый массив

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

Сигнатура метода ResizeArrray должна быть именно такой как в коде у Вас?
Если нет, то я бы на Вашем месте поставил бы у данного метода возвращаемый тип string[], а в теле метода:
1. Создал вспомогательный массив с размерность на 1 больше.
2. Перекопировал туда данные
В главном методе к массиву присваиваете, то что вернет ResizeArray и все. Если конечно, по условию такой способ решения приемлем.
Либо посмотрите как реализован Array.Resize:https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3 и перепишите под себя

Answer (score 1):

```
static void ResizeArray(ref string[] array, int newSize)
{
  if (array.Length != newSize)
  {
    string[] newArray = new string[newSize];
    Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 0, Math.Min(array.Length, newSize));
    array = newArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, у топикстартера задание вручную реализовать увеличение массива и пользоваться встроенными методами нельзя, в том числе `Array.Copy` (да и `Math.Min` тоже).